# How to compile linphone 3.12.0 for Debian 9?

Tags: compilation, version, linphone

Two years later i compile linphone v. 3.12.0 for Debian 9. For do make it, i take repo:

```
git clone https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-desktop.git --recursive
```

... and compile by instruction in readme.md

But in current time, in this repo very newed version 4.x.x, this version is broken: lost many *.qm files:

```
Generating qrc source app-library_automoc.dir/qrc_i18n_FDECJIYE5GSB34.cpp
RCC: Error in '/home/xi/work/develop/cpp/linphone/linphone-desktop/build/linphone-app/assets/languages/i18n.qrc': Cannot find file 'da.qm'
AUTORCC: error: process for app-library_automoc.dir/qrc_i18n_FDECJIYE5GSB34.cpp failed:
RCC: Error in '/home/xi/work/develop/cpp/linphone/linphone-desktop/build/linphone-app/assets/languages/i18n.qrc': Cannot find file 'da.qm'
rcc failed...
```

And in repository tag i can't found tag by 3.12.0.

Q: How to get correct linphone source for 3.12.0 version?

Answer (score 0):

Empirically, I found a commit that is guaranteed to be build. It contains the version of the console linphone (linphonec) I need. Switching to the desired commit and build happens like this:

```
git clone https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-desktop.git --recursive
cd linphone-desktop
git checkout -b linphone_3_12_0 d8f1eea6
git submodule update --init --recursive

export Qt5_DIR="/opt/qt_5_9_6/5.9.6/gcc_64/lib/cmake"
export PATH="/opt/qt_5_9_6/5.9.6/gcc_64/bin/:$PATH"
rm -Rf ./OUTPUT
rm -Rf ./WORK
./prepare.py -DENABLE_V4L=NO
make
```

Before build, it need install packages:

```
apt-get install gcc c++ make cmake git autoconf autogen automake libtool yasm 
apt-get install libmbedtls10 libmbedtls-dev libcunit1 libcunit1-dev 
apt-get install libx11-xcb-dev libx11-xcb1 libglew-dev
apt-get install libbsd-dev libbsd0 libv4l-dev libv4l-0
apt-get install pkg-config, doxygen, libasound2-dev, python-pystache, python3-pystache
apt-get install python-psycopg2 python-pip python3-pip
```

After build, the software have next versions:

```
./linphone --version
linphone 4.1.1-662-gd8f1eea6

./linphonec --version
version: 3.12.0
```